# Use of Table Layout inside scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-scrollview, android-tablelayout

Hello i am new in android
I was trying to use scroll view and somewhere on internet i found this code

```
<ScrollView 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fillViewport="true"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignParentStart="true">  
   <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
```

This code works perfectly but i don't understand what is the use of 
`android:stretchColumns="1">`?.If I change `stretchColumns="1"`to `"3"`or any number i am not getting any changes in my `scroll view`.

Comment: You can use GridView instead

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Comment: Thank u brother.

Comment: way to go bro !! welcome to the community !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TableLayout can specify certain columns as shrinkable or stretchable by calling setColumnShrinkable()(xml:android:shrinkColumns) or setColumnStretchable()(xml:android:stretchColumns).

If marked as shrinkable, the column width can be shrunk to fit the table into its parent object. If marked as stretchable, it can expand in width to fit any extra space.

The total width of the table is defined by its parent container. It is important to remember that a column can be both shrinkable and stretchable .

For details information you may visit

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

check out this example

```
<TableLayout
android:shrinkColumns="2,3"
android:stretchColumns="1,3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: That was helpful.but i am not seeing any effect on my scroll view when i change the strechcolumn